# Determination of area of circular object in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to determine area of circular object in image below using MATLAB. Can someone explain codes for doing that? I got thresholded image but I did not proceed more.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works is that you show us what you've tried (by posting code) and explain what doesn't work. You're unlikely to get someone to write code from scratch for you. So show us what you've tried so far... See [ask].

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before adding them to your question. The ones I've removed have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the binary image is `img`, and it contains only values 0 (background) and 1 (object), or it is a logical array containing `true` and `false`, and all the object pixels are considered part of the object, then `sum(img(:))` is the area of the object in pixels.

If the segmented image contains multiple objects, or noise, it will have to be filtered first to leave only the pixels that belong to the one object.

To convert the area in pixels to an area in physical units you need to know the size of a pixel. This is often obtained by adding a ruler to the image.

Comment: Problem then is that there's no ruler on the image, and also there is speckle outside the image, as well as the circle's edges not being a perfect line. This will distort your final result.

Comment: @Adriaan: hadn’t noticed the speckles. Can’t see those on a phone! :)